# How to make a Bootstrap row background color fill the rest of the page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When we make a webpage with Bootstrap, we use rows that we put in a container, so if do this with 2 rows, how to make the 2nde one to fill the entire page ?

I.e if I have those 2 rows:

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuMBF.png)

How do I make the 2nde one (the blue one) to fill the rest of the page ?

Thank you

The HTML code is:

```
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row row1">

        <br>

    </div>

    <div class="row row2">

        <br>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
```

And the css is:

```
.row1{
    background-color: orange;
}

.row2{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**p.s:** I just want to transform the rows properties, not use one row and color the rest of the page with the backgroud color of the body.

Comment: Put the first one in `.container` and the 2nd one in `.container-fluid`? You need to post your code, too.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I just tried your solution it does not work

Comment: Can you clarify what the question/problem is? It's not very clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use flex layout to implement what you want. Here is an example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
.row1{
    background-color: orange;
}

.row2{
    background-color: blue;
}
.container-fluid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
.row:last-child {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row row1">

        <br>

    </div>

    <div class="row row2">

        <br>

    </div>

</div>
```

A [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cshao/wv419y9g/1/) is also made for reference.

Some explanation for the key code:

- `display: flex;`: use flex layout for items inside of `display: flex`.
- `flex-direction: column;`: arrange `.row`s vertically.
- `flex: 1;`: make the last child of `.container-fluid` (`.row2` in your case) grow/shrink automatically.